# tf.function property in pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, autograd

I'm a beginner in pytorch, and I have some functions that are needed to implement in network.

My question is: is there any way like **tf.function**, or should I use "class(nn.Module)" with variable?

For example, let X be a 10x2 matrix . In pseudo-code:

```
a = Variable(1.0) 
b = Variable(1.0)
Y = a*X[:,0]**2 + b*X[:,1]
```

Comment: What is your function output? `aX^2 + bX`?

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: Especially, I will implement a cnn that gives me two output (a and b), then I will calculate an energy that is Eo = (a^6 - b^5)^2. I have energy targets like Et, so my cnn will try to minimize 0.5*(Eo-Et)^2.

Answer (score 3):

In PyTorch you don't need things like `tf.function`, you just use normal Python code (because of the dynamic graph).

Please give more detailed example (with code) of what you're trying to do if the above doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Thank you Sergey !. The answer that I tried to find is "you just use normal Python code (because of the dynamic graph)".